# How to "jump" to a line of a file, rather than read file line by line, using Perl

Tags: perl, loops, while-loop

I am opening a file containing a single but very long column.  I want to retrieve from it just a short segment, starting at a specified line and ending at another specified line.  Currently, my script is reading the file line by line until the desired lines are found.  I am using:

```
my ( $from, $to ) = ( some line number, some larger line number );    
my $count = 1;
my @seq = ();

while ( <SEQUENCE> ) {
    print "$_ for $count\n";
    $count++;

    while ( $count >= $from && $count <= $to ) {
         push( @seq, $_ );
         last;
    }
}
print "seq is: @seq\n";
```

Input looks like:

```
A
G
T
C
A
G
T
C
.
.
.
```

How might I "jump" to where I want to be?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use seek to move to the correct portion of the file. ref: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html

This works on bytes, not on lines, so generally if you need to use line seeking its not an option. However, since you're working on a fixed length line (2 or 3 bytes depending on your platform's EOL encoding) you can multiply the line length by the line you want (0 indexed) and you'll be at the correct location for reading.

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to know that all the lines are of exactly the same length (accounting for line ending characters, generally 1 byte on Unix/Linux and 2 on Windows), you can use `seek` to go directly to a specified point in the file

The `seek` function lets you specify a file position in bytes/characters, not in lines. In the general case, the only way to go to a specified line number is to read from the beginning and skip that many lines (minus one).

Unless you have an index mapping line numbers to byte offsets; then you can look up the specified line number in the index and use `seek` to jump to that location. To do this, you have to build the index separately (a process that will require reading through the entire file) and make sure the index is always up to date. If the file changes frequently, this is likely to be impractical.

I'm not aware of any existing tools for building and using such an index, but I wouldn't be surprised if they exist. But it should be easy enough to roll your own.

But unless scanning the file to find the line number you want is a significant performance bottleneck, I wouldn't bother with the extra complexity.

Comment: i suppose there is no way to speed up the line by line `<>` reading?

Comment: @ES55: I expect that already goes as fast as the Perl developers can make it. Text files, at least on Unix-like and Windows-like systems, just aren't randomly line-addressable. If you can either enforce fixed-length lines or switch to a binary format, you can fetch random records. Or you might consider switching to some kind of database. It all depends on what you're trying to do and how many times you need to access the file compared to how often it changes.

Comment: I use a mac, so unix-like. The files are chromosome sequences, they won't change frequently but will be accessed frequently. The `seek` command is working well so far, very fast.  I am sure there are databases and software available to do what I am doing, but I don't mind reinventing a wheel or two toward the end of learning something about programing.

Comment: @ES55: Still, you might consider inventing a binary format with fixed-length records. It looks like you could save 50% of the file size by omitting the newlines. With text, if you accidentally add a character to a line (say, a trailing space that you're likely not to see in an editor), it could throw off the whole thing.

Comment: my single column files are without error, no white spaces, i used a script to columnize the rows of a large fasta file.  but your point about binary files is taken, but I'd have to learn about those.  The path I am on is, at the moment, easier for me to take.

Comment: @ES55: And text files are easier to view amd manipulate with other tools. If the extra size isn't a problem, it sounds like you're in good shape.